Does "two of the best brands" mean the number of the best brands is { only two } or { two or more } or { more than two }?
For instance we may consider the following sentence (I came up with it myself):
(1) Ford and Honda are two of the best-selling car brands in the US.
Does (1) mean (1a), (1b) or (1c)?:
(1a) There are only two best-selling car brands in the US: Ford and Honda.
(1b) Besides Ford and Honda, there may be other best-selling car brands in the US.
(1c) Besides Ford and Honda, there must be other best-selling car brands in the US.

What is this question really about? may versus must? How can 1) equal any of those?

It is a very odd question to ask!  Because you already know from common knowledge that there are very many different brands of car.  The function of the sentence is to identify two of the popular brands, not for you to read between the lines and imply how many brands of car there are - you already know that!

So Lambies point is that 1 doesn't mean a, b or c, though it probably implies "c".  The sentence "I'm an Englishman" doesn't mean "I have a head", although it probably implies that fact.

Dear Lovii, I really hope that you are not suggesting that @Lambie is a drunkard?

What if it said "two of the better-selling car brands"?  Would it necessarily imply that the speaker believes there is at least one other brand that dramatically outsells them, and at least one other brand that they dramatically outsell?  Or does the comparative merely entail two categories?  May you lose sleep over it.

@JamesK The difference between your { 1 doesn't mean a, b or c, though it probably implies "c" } and Lambie's { How can 1) equal any of those? } is that your sentence is useful and Lambie's is totally useless like a spam.

@TimR I can't feel what shades your sentence "May you lose sleep over it" is conveying. Is it conveying something negative (rude)?

@Lovii:  No ruder than your questions.

When a number is used in a partitive construction:

Two of the richest people in the world are Bill Gates and Elon Musk.

does it mean to the speaker
a) they and they alone constitute the set "the richest people in the world"
b) they and possibly some (unnamed) others constitute the set   "the richest people in the world"
or
c) they and definitely some (unnamed) others constitute the set  "the richest people in the world" ?
or
d) they and possibly one or more (unnamed) others constitute the set  "the richest people in the world"
or
e) they and definitely one or more (unnamed) others constitute the set  "the richest people in the world"
I'd say e) is correct answer. There are at least three "richest people in the world".
So the rule is number + 1 at a minimum.
Why?
Because no sane speaker would say something like:

Romulus and Remus are  two of the famous twins who founded Rome.

or

Those are ten of the Ten Commandments.

or

Those are nine of the positions on the field in the game of baseball.


OP's query:


Ford and Honda are two of the best-selling car brands in the US.


If the sentence was.
1) Ford is one of the best-selling car brands in the US.
It means that
Besides Ford, there must be other best-selling car brand/brands in the US. (more than one best selling brand, may be more than two).
If we want to convey 1a, the sentence would be:
Ford and Honda are the best-selling car brands in the US.
The original sentence means only 1c:
(1c) Besides Ford and Honda, there must be other best-selling car brands in the US.(more than two best selling brand)
